# How to run procedure without parameter in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

How to run procedure without parameter in Teradata 
I'm trying with : `call db1.proc_dbOSA()`

Error Msg:

```
Call failed 3707: PROC_DBOSA: Syntax error, expected something 
like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier between ‘(‘ and ‘)’
```

New Procedure with error result.
When i run only code then everything works ok.

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE db1.proc_dbOSA()
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM db1.LOG_dbOSA;      
INSERT INTO
    db1.LOG_dbOSA
        (StoreNo, IDX, Flow, Status, MRP, OSA_IDX, OSA_AC)

WITH a AS (
SELECT    
    c.StoreCode,
    CAST(SUBSTRING(c.ArticleCode FROM 13 FOR 6) AS INT) AS IDX,
    RpType,
    CASE
        WHEN  c.MinimumTargetStockWrpl >= l.MinimumTargetStockWrpl THEN CAST(l.MinimumTargetStockWrpl AS INT)
        WHEN  c.MinimumTargetStockWrpl <  l.MinimumTargetStockWrpl THEN CAST(c.MinimumTargetStockWrpl AS INT)
    End AS StoreMin,
    c.ValUnrestrictedStock
FROM 
   db1.tab1 c
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT    
        StoreCode,
        ArticleCode,
        MinimumTargetStockWrpl    
    FROM 
        db1.tab1
    WHERE
        ProcessingDate = CURRENT_DATE - 14
    ) l ON c.StoreCode = l.StoreCode AND c.ArticleCode = l.ArticleCode
WHERE
    c.ProcessingDate = CURRENT_DATE AND c.MinimumTargetStockWrpl IS NOT NULL AND l.MinimumTargetStockWrpl IS NOT NULL AND l.MinimumTargetStockWrpl > 0
)

, t AS
(
SELECT    
    CAST(SUBSTRING(ArticleCode FROM 13 FOR 6) AS INT) AS IDX,
    RpType, 
    ArticlesPlanner
FROM 
    DWH_db_V.STK_B_ARTICLE_DAY_V
WHERE 
    ProcessingDate = CURRENT_DATE AND StoreCode = 'DR04'
)

SELECT 
    a.StoreCode,
    a.IDX,
    t.RpType,
    t.ArticlesPlanner,
    a.RpType,
    CASE
        WHEN a.ValUnrestrictedStock > 0 THEN 1
        WHEN a.ValUnrestrictedStock <= 0 THEN 0
    End AS OSA_IDX,
    CASE
        WHEN a.ValUnrestrictedStock >= StoreMin THEN 1
        WHEN a.ValUnrestrictedStock < StoreMin THEN 0
    End AS OSA_AC
FROM 
    a
LEFT JOIN
    t ON t.IDX = a.IDX;     
End;
```

BTEQ Error:
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
Call proc_dbOSA;

Call proc_dbOSA;
                $
 *** Failure 3707 Syntax error, expected something like '(' between the word
  'proc_dbOSA' and ';'.
                Statement# 1, Info =18
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

Call proc_dbOSA();
 *** Failure 3707 PROC_DBOSA:Syntax error, expected something like a name or
  a Unicode delimited identifier between '(' and ')'.
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the right SP -- properly qualified, i.e. database_name.proc_dbOSA()?  Can you post your SP create text?

Comment: Ravioli i edited my main post -> added the SP create text

Comment: hmmm now is working but with diffrend procedure is not working :/

Comment: Your SP looks OK to me.  Go ahead and post the new "not working" SP.

Comment: i edited my main post one more time ;)

Comment: Nothing really stands out in your `SP` -- it looks OK.  Are you getting the same error message as you originally posted?  The only potential "strange" thing is you have multiple `CTE`s in your `INSERT`, but I doubt that's it.  Have you tried calling it via `BTEQ` as well?  It may give more error information than `SQLA`.

Comment: The error is the same... 
I will back with BTEQ result in 1h ;)

Comment: Ok, i added btqe error.

Comment: Thanks.  The call and error you posted don't include the parentheses.  Do you get the same message in `BTEQ` when you run: `CALL db1.proc_dbOSA()`

Comment: Call proc_dbOSA();
 *** Failure 3707 PROC_DBOSA:Syntax error, expected something like a name or
  a Unicode delimited identifier between '(' and ')'.
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

Comment: Hmm...I'm not sure.  Does the `SP` associated with the code you posted above belong to `tab1` or `db1`?  The only other thing I can think of is maybe you are accidentally calling an old `SP` that took parameters and not the actual `SP` you "think" you are calling, since your `CALL` is unqualified.

Comment: I have only one SP in my db.

Tab1 should be db1. I changed names because i dont want to publicate a real names.

Comment: I edited the code on tab1 -> db1 sorry for my mistake on names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored procedures do not support the following:

EXPLAIN and USING request modifiers within a stored procedure

EXECUTE macro statement

WITH clause within a stored procedure.

Stored procedures, as well as macros, do not support the following query logging statements:

BEGIN QUERY LOGGING

END QUERY LOGGING

FLUSH QUERY LOGGING

REPLACE QUERY LOGGING